# Admob ad not showing on blackberry shows on android

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook

I converted .apk for android to .bar. Everything works in the game but admob ad is not showing at all. Can anyone please tell me what can i change to make ads available on .bar file? I looked online but cant find any answers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. It seems only mobfox has content for PlayBook

Answer (score 1):

Most likely request is sent, but Admob doesn't have any content to show on Playbook..